# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tree.h'

Tags: c++, file, include

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and I have included all my files (tree.h, node.h). But the program gives me an error saying:

```
1>c:\users\NAME\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project name\project name\project name.cpp(6):
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tree.h': No such file or directory.
```

Anyone have any clue?

Comment: Make sure both files are located in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrote the two header files make sure that they have been defined at the top:

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H
//code
#endif
```

But also try moving the .h files into the same folder as your .cpp file. If this fixes the problem you probably have to set a custom link path for the compiler. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with Visual Studio 2013 but you might find it in the documentation.

I think this might help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/588022/Using-Additional-Include-Directories

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks for the recommendation :D

Answer (score 0):

This means u didn't have this file.
if you don't want to use this file, u can remove include of this file from project_name.cpp .
Also u can add this file to your project manualy.

Comment: The file I want to #include is IN the project folder called "Header files". I used #include "tree.h" on top of main too.

Comment: You'll seem to have a problem with your include path (`-I`) options. Your 'Header-Folder' **should** be accessible for the compiler. Do you have subfolders or other fancy stuff there?

Comment: @Sheppard_ It means the compiler can't access/find the file! That's a huge difference from stating not having this file at all.